# Naming output files where original file name retained without file extension using ModelBuilder iteration?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, modelbuilder, iterator

I am using iterate raster in ModelBuilder to create hillshade and slope simultaneously for many rasters within one folder.

My problem is when I name the output files.

Whenever I use, %Name%, the model fails because the resulting output names include the file extension.

If I use %n%, it only creates one file.

Is there another way of naming output files where the original file name is retained but without the file extension?

Answer (score 2):

The [Parse Path (ModelBuilder)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//004000000008000000) should be able to meet your requirement.

> The Parse Path tool parses the input into its file, path, name, or
>   extension. The output can be used as in-line variables in the output
>   name of other tools.

If not, then a diagram of your model and more details would be helpful to try and provide a more targeted Answer.

Comment: Oh thanks, it worked, however, when I tried to combine Parse path with calculate value (because I also need to remove the hyphen from my filename), the resulting outputs do not match the initial output. I'm still trying to figure it out

Comment: @user26845 You need to add a precondition from the parse output to a tool so that the parse output does not get ahead of the tool output.

Comment: I though this was going to be the solution to my problem but it did not work. The file I'm trying to parse is 'safer.A2009241.250m_16_days_NIR_reflectance.tif' and the name I get is 'safer.A2009241'. It's trowing away part of the name.

Comment: In my case I solved my 'filename with more than two . (dots)' using the Calculate Value tool and the python expression '.'.join(f.split('.')[:-1]), where f is the name variable